# How to disable BadValueError (required field) value in Google App Engine during scanning all records?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to scan all records to check if there is not errors inside data.

How can I disable BadValueError to no break scan on lack of required field?

Consider that I can not change `StringProperty` to not required and such properties can be tenths in real code - so such workaround is not useful?

```
class A(db.Model):
  x = db.StringProperty(required = True)

for instance in A.all():
  # check something
  if something(instance):
    instance.delete()
```

Can I use some function to read `datastore.Entity` directly to avoid such problems with not need validation?

Comment: I've not tried this, but here's an idea. Override the StringProperty class, and override the validate() method - just get it to return True. Then change your x field to your new implementation of StringProperty. When you load the entities, your new (ie empty) validate method will run instead, therefore bypassing the raising of the BadValueError. Maybe this will work, maybe it wont - I don't have time to try right now

Comment: @GwynHowell Thanks but I specified that I want avoid this solution at all costs.

Comment: You have two choices as I see it, modify the class for the duration of the check, removing the `required=True` but you have said you do not want to change the model definition so thats out.  Or use the low level api, but then you don't have access to any functionality in the class and your not using the model at all.  With your constraints I don't believe it is possible

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found for this problem was to use a resilient query, it ignores any exception thrown by a query, you can try this:

```
def resilient_query(query):
    query_iter = iter(query)
    while True:
            next_result = query_iter.next()
            #check something
            yield next_result
        except Exception, e:
            next_result.delete() 

query = resilient_query(A.query())
```

Comment: It is partial solution since all invalid records is killed - it not allow to fix some invalid records.

Comment: well I deleted the entity to match your example, but it shows you how to ignore exceptions which was the main purpose of your question, you can choose to fix your empty entities or to delete them

Comment: Yes indeed. I want to find some solution which allow to read entity without required attributes without code changes in model definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ndb, you can load all your models as an ndb.Expando, then modify the values. This doesn't appear to be possible in db because you cannot specify a kind for a Query in db that differs from your model class.

Even though your model is defined in db, you can still use ndb to fix your entities:

```py
# Setup a new ndb connection with ndb.Expando as the default model.
conn = ndb.make_connection(default_model=ndb.Expando)
# Use this connection in our context.
ndb.set_context(ndb.make_context(conn=conn))

# Query for all A kinds
for a in ndb.Query(kind='A'):
  if a.x is None:
    a.x = 'A more appropriate value.'
    # Re-put the broken entity.
    a.put()
```

Also note that this (and other solutions listed) will be subject to whatever time limits you are restricted to (i.e. 60 seconds on an App Engine frontend). If you are dealing with large amounts of data you will most likely want to write a custom map reduce job to do this.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question about the connection. db does not expose the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `default` property option to some distinct value that does not exist otherwise.

```
class A(db.Model):
  x = db.StringProperty(required = True, default = <distinct value>)
```

Then load properties and check for this value.

Comment: Bad idea if this value is dynamic half-solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the _check_initialized(self) method of ndb.Model in your own Model subclass and replace the default logic with your own logic (or skip altogether as needed).